# How to find the characteristics of a bunch of word Clusters?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis, data-science

**My Motivations**  I'm trying to learn German and realized there's a confounding fact with the structure of German: every noun has a gender which seems unrelated to the noun itself in many cases.

Unlike languages such as English, each noun has a different definite article, depending on gender: *der* (masculine), *die* (feminine), and *das* (neuter). For example:
*das Mädchen* ("the girl"), *der Rock* ("the skirt), *die Hose* ("the trousers/pants"). So, there seems to be no correlation between gender assignment of nouns and their meanings.

**The Data**
I gathered up to 5000 German words with **3 columns (das, der, die)** for each word with 1's and 0's. So, my data is already clustered with one hot encoding and I'm not trying to predict anything.

**Why I'm here** I am clueless on where to start, how to approach this problem as the concept of distance in clustering doesn't make sense to me in this setting. I can't think of a way to generate an understandable description of these clusters. The mixed data makes it impossible for me to think of some hard-coded metrics for evaluation.

**So, my question is:**
I want to find some patterns, some characteristics of these words that made them fall in a specific cluster. I don't know if I'm making any sense but some people managed to find some patterns already (for example word endings, elongated long objects tend to be masculine etc., etc) and I believe ML/AI could do a way better job at this. Would it be possible for me to do something like this?

**Some personal thoughts**
While I was doing some research (perhaps, naive), I realized the potential options are [decision trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) and [cobweb algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_(clustering)). Also, I was thinking if I could just scrape a few images (say 5) for every word and try to run some image classification and see the intermediate NN's to see if any specific shapes support a specific object gender. In addition to that, I was wondering whether scraping the data of google n-gram viewers of these words could help in anyway. I couldn't think of a way to use NLP or its sub domains.

**Alternatives** If everything I just wrote sounds nonsensical, please suggest me a way to make visual representations of my dataframe (more like nodes and paths with images at nodes, one for each cluster) in Python so that I could make pictorial mind maps and try to by heart them.

**The ultimate purpose is to make learning German simpler** for myself and possibly for others

Comment: I see you have posted this to Linguistics. It is considered polite, in the Stackiverse, to have only one copy of your question in play at any time.  You should delete this version.

Comment: Hey! I'm sorry about that. I wasn't aware of that. I am just making sure people actually get to see it. I was just hoping that people in Data Science might have a perspective.